# Force a postback inside a WebMethod

Tags: c#, javascript, webmethod

I am using a 3rd party control for GIS map related functions. 
I had the need to call a C# Method from within javascript. I chose to use `PageMethods` like this:

```
PageMethods.getFeature(x,y)
```

Works like a charm as long as you convert your method to a `[WebMethod]`

In this method I am passing in the coordinates of the mouse and it returns me map features. That I will highlight on the map.

From researching I found that you cant directly access the UI from inside a [WebMethod] so I decided to set a session variable and postback. On postback if the session variables exist I would make the necessary UI changes.

My `WebMethod` looks like this:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public static void getFeature(float x, float y)
        {...
        some code in here. 
        }
```

**Update**
This is my jQUery:

```
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function (e) {
            $(".MyMap").click(function (e) {
                var posX = $(this).position().left;
                var posY = $(this).position().top;
                PageMethods.getFeature(e.pageX-posX, e.pageY-posY);
              });
        });
    </script>
```

How do I force a postback inside of a `WebMethod`. Most of the ways I know to postback don't work.

Comment: You can't cause the browser to post a form to the server, from the server. This is a client side operation. You could write JavaScript that causes a postback when it receives a response from the web service.

Comment: @BenRobinson That's a good point... hmmmm.  The javascript is used to get the MouseClick event and know where a image was clicked. That's passed to the method in c#. Is there another way to achieve this without using `WebMethod`. I am using jQuery for the javascript function.

Comment: What do you want to happen as a result of the jQuery ajax call?  MVC and Web API controllers can also process ajax requests, Web API is particularly powerful and flexible.

Comment: It should call some code that takes the mouse location data and converts it to Lat and Long. I have a 3rd party library that does everything. It was originally designed for WinForms and then eventually retrofitted to work with Asp.NET pages. I just need to pass in the mouse location of the user clicks on the mapcontrol which is really just a html image control.

Comment: A web method should work fine for that, why do you think you need to force a postback?

Comment: I am getting the data back correctly. I now need to access the map which in on the UI (its an img). A web method cannot access the UI. That's my issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "access the map", if you want to do something in the browser you can return data from your web method to a JavaScript callback function and then do whatever you wish in the UI.

Comment: Oh... I updated my question with the jQuery code. How would I create the javascript callbackfunction

Comment: I would consult the jQuery docs for ajax requests, this sia a good starting point http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: OK. Thanks for your help. I guess go ahead and put your answer with a summary of what you suggested and Ill accept it. This way it helps other people if they have the same screwed up concept ;)

Comment: I think the bottom line here is that, as much as possible, stuff doesn't require server side interaction should be happening on the client side. If you need additional details from the server or need to send some data to the server, it's best to use AJAX rather than doing a postback. When I first started working with Web Forms I relied heavily on postback, but have discovered that properly using AJAX techniques (rather than postback or UpdatePanel) leads to a more efficient and simpler to maintain site, and allows for a better user experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Special Thanks to @BenRobinson for assisting me in the right direction. Here is what I came up with. I am posting this for other people who may make a similar mistake. The short answer is: **You Cant

My main issue was I was using a `[WebMethod]` so my c# code could be called from `jQuery`. This worked perfectly until I needed access to the UI. Well technically a 'WebMethod' is almost like calling a web service. You cant have a remote web service update the UI. What you can do is after your function in jQuery runs that calls the `[WebMethod]`, is have it call a new page (`window.location`). That location can call the original page (in my case Default.aspx).  I passed parameters in the request field that I needed to send to the UI, and I basically put code in that if on load you see a particular request variable then do something... It worked like a charm.

Here's a rough example:
In my jQuery page I did this (to navigate to a new page):

```
window.location.replace("ZoomAndCenter.aspx?x=" + (e.pageX - posX) + "&y=" + (e.pageY - posY))
```

Here is what my ZoomAndCenter.aspx looked like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                int x = 0;
                double y = 0;
                x = Int32.Parse(Request["x"].ToString());
                y = Double.Parse(Request["y"].ToString());
                //Run some more code
                Response.Redirect("Default.aspx?Param1=xxxx&Param2=xxxx");
                //passed the params in the redirect.
             }
```

Then in the Default.aspx

```
 if(request["param1"] == "something")
{
//do something
}
```